# how to create a Zend_Db_Table_Select through a string query php

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

I have been taking a look, for if there any way to create a Zend_Db_Table_Select or  Zend_Db_Select instance with a literal sql query. I mean, I've got a complex query and I want through this query create an object of that one.
I have been reading the docs for this classes and I didn't find anything. I guess that this is not possible.

Do you know something about it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to write this in your model:

```
public function customQuery ($table, $id) {
    return $this
        ->getDefaultAdapter()
        ->query("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE id = ?",
            array($table,$id)
        )
        ->fetchAll()
    ;
}
```

and also one more [link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.statement.html) would be very useful to you

Comment: Thank you very much, interesting way. I'm going to try it